# Database migration in loopback4

Tags: database-migration, loopback4

I wanted to create database tables from model definition in loopback4. How to do that using loopback4's **Auto update** functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `npm run migrate` script in the LoopBack4 application. See https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Database-migrations.html for details. Please note that there is an option to drop existing schemas before creating a new one.